# Xvfb failed to start when running second screen

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, xvfb, xserver

Two scripts `first.sh` and `second.sh` are to be used to run `test.sh` and `test2.sh` headlessly using `Xvfb` on Ubuntu 16.04.

**Problem:** After running `first.sh`, we get an error when we run `second.sh`.

> xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start

What went wrong and how can we fix it? Thanks!

**first.sh**

```
#/bin/sh

# Clean Process Space:
kill -9 `pidof xvfb-run`
kill -9 `pidof java`
kill -9 `pidof Xvfb`

# Launch a virtual screen
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:1

# Launch the script
xvfb-run "/home/me/test.sh" &

history -c
```

**second.sh**

```
#/bin/sh

# Launch a virtual screen
Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:2

# Launch the script
xvfb-run "/home/me/test2.sh" &

history -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the option -a to your command line, like:

```
xvfb-run -a "/home/me/test2.sh"
```

The option is a shortage for --auto-servernum which tries to find a free server number before opening it.